# Automatic author in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

all. I'm working on the admin for my django site, and I've run into an obstacle.

I've got an `Entry` model and a `Related` model. The `Related` model has two foreign key fields: one to the `Entry` model (`entry`) and one to django's `User` model (`author`). The `Related` model is considered a "sub-model" of the `Entry` model, and each user can only have one `Related` per `Entry`.

In the admin, `Related` is edited inline with `Entry`. As I have it, the admin shows only one extra `Related` at a time, and it automatically fills the `author` field with the current user:

```
from django.contrib import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Entry(models.Model):
    pass

class Related(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('entry', 'author')




from django.contrib import admin

class RelatedInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Related
    exclude = ('author',)
    max_num = 1

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (RelatedInline,)
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in filter(lambda obj: isinstance(obj, Related), instances):
             if instance.__dict__.get('author', None) is None:
                 instance.author = request.user
                 instance.save()
        formset.save_m2m()
```

The problem is that if a user wants to edit an entry which already has a `Related` by *anyone*, then only that one related field will be shown.

If possible, I wonder if anyone has any ideas about how I could keep a setup similar to this, but have the admin automatically display the user's `related` if it exists and an empty form if it doesn't. Barring that, I would just get rid of the line `max_num = 1` and replace it with `extra = 1`. Of course, this would mean that a "new related" form would show even if the user already had one for the current entry, so I wonder if anyone has any idea about how I would catch a possible `IntegrityError` and let the user know that an error had occurred.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101979/django-admin-filter-objects-for-inline-formset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is pretty simple.  You just need to add a `queryset` function to your `RelatedInline` class, specifying which inline to show.  If the returned queryset has at least one member, the first will be shown.  If the queryset is empty, a single blank inline will be shown!

```
class RelatedInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Related
    exclude = ('author',)
    max_num = 1

    def queryset(request):
        return Related.objects.filter(author = request.user)
```